# github action skipped job

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this action:

```
name: Tests
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      os:
        type: choice
        required: true
        description: the os that will be tested.
        default: ANDROID
        options:
        - IOS
        - ANDROID
jobs:

  LA_CHECKS:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        la_checks: [[la, las331],[la2,las993]]
    name: ${{ matrix.la[1] }}
    runs-on: DOCKER
    container: scripts
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/templates/la_check
        with:
          precondition: ${{ matrix.la_checks[0] }}


  Install_FR1:
    if: ${{ always() && github.event.inputs.os == 'ANDROID' }}
    needs: [LA_CHECKS]
    runs-on: DOCKER
    container: scripts
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/templates/install
        with:
          d_id: fr1

  FR1_EXEC:
    needs: [Install_FR1]
    if: needs.Install_FR1.result == 'success'
    runs-on: DOCKER
    container: scripts
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/templates/device
        with:
          d_id: fr1

  Uninstall_FR1:
    if: ${{ always() && github.event.inputs.os == 'ANDROID' }}
    needs: [FR1_EXEC]
    runs-on: DOCKER
    container: scripts
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: ./.github/templates/uninstall
        with:
          device_id: fr1
```

All jobs are successfully executed.
Except job `FR1_EXEC` and one matrix action in `LA_CHECKS`:

```
- LA_CHECK1 = OK
- LA_CHECK2 = NOK
- Install_FR1 = OK
- FR1_EXEC = Skipped (WHY???)
- Uninstall_FR1 = OK
```

I tried it even without the if-condition because I thought it is enough to define the previous step in the `needs` section of `FR1_EXEC`.

I always get the message in github `This check was skipped`.

I dont see my mistake.
I am working on a feature branch.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/2018495026 (without the containers and scripts) and it executed all the jobs successfully with your implementation. Is it a public repo available for fork?

Comment: No it is not public. In youre Pipeline all the matrix jobs were successful. In mine the second one fails. Could that be an issue?

Comment: You could check this by removing the `always()` from the `Install_FR1` to check if this job is executed in that case (when one of the matrix fails). If it's not executed, that may be the reason why the `FR1_EXEC` is skipped (but it would be quite a strange behavior, without a clear display on the workflow output from the Github UI).

Comment: Found the Problem. It Was indeed the failing matrix job that disables the job

Comment: Great! We both learnt something today 